# Can a Facebook checkin deal be accessed outside of the mobile FB site or official application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

If you create a checkin deal, are users still able to get benefits if they checkin via an app built on the graph API that has access to the user's checkin permission?

If so, how would the deal be displayed? Let's assume that the app is something very similar to linkstore.ru/fbplaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question via a response from Facebook:

Only facebook deals partners will be allowed to access the deals API.

So, no.